# Building a probabilistic relationship between two variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability

Suppose I have a set data point pairs (x, y). If I wanted to predict the value of y for some given value of x, I could perform a regression on the data points, and find a function which relates x and y.

But what if I wanted to know what the probability would be of y being between two values, for a given value of x? The regression method I mentioned before would just give the expected value of y, but I now want to consider the probability of y being in a certain range.

What are some methods that could be used to do this?

Comment: Do you have some example data?

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches.

One simple approach would be to adapt binomial regression (such as logistic regression). Record a 1 every time a y-value is between the two limits, 0 when it is not, and model that as some convenient function of x (depending on what kinds of relationship you want to entertain)

Comment: Thanks. But suppose that I wanted to query my data with each new x-value, rather than solving a regression for a particular y-value. Would a Gaussian process be suitable for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression). It's quite popular in econometrics. It's used to forecast quantiles conditional on inputs. For instance, you could forecast what is 90th percentile given inputs X. This is not exactly what you're asking but, it can be useful